# Problem creating form nothing shows up in layout view or form view but it does in design view

Tags: ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

When creating additional forms I have created a series of text boxes in design view.

When I select form view or layout view it comes up blank.

When I look at the form property sheet allow layout view and allow form view are both set to yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your form's record source is empty, i.e. it contains no records. The form has no records to show and thus appears empty.

And it's either set to not allow adding new records, or the record source is read-only.